# AngularJS failed to upload file express

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, express, ng-file-upload

I am trying to upload a file to express ( so i can upload it to mongoDB later on). However, when I try to upload a file to express, i print out the response data, and it seems like nothing is getting passed in.

Im using ng-file-upload.min.js. Can anyone help me out?

#### script.js

```
var app = angular.module('fileUpload', ['ngFileUpload']);

app.controller('MyCtrl', ['$scope', 'Upload', '$timeout', function ($scope, Upload, $timeout) {
    $scope.uploadFiles = function(files, errFiles) {
        $scope.files = files;
        $scope.errFiles = errFiles;
        angular.forEach(files, function(file) {
            file.upload = Upload.upload({
                url: '/uploadFile',
                data: {file: file}
            });

            file.upload.then(function (response) {
                $timeout(function () {
                    file.result = response.data;
                });
            }, function (response) {
                if (response.status > 0)
                    $scope.errorMsg = response.status + ': ' + response.data;
            }, function (evt) {
                file.progress = Math.min(100, parseInt(100.0 *evt.loaded / evt.total));
            });
        });
    }
}]);
```

#### Server.js

```
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path'); //core module 
var databaseUrl = "localhost:27017/DB"; // default env
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var multer  = require('multer');
var storage =   multer.diskStorage({
  destination: function (req, file, callback) {
    callback(null, './uploads');
  },
  filename: function (req, file, callback) {
    callback(null, file.fieldname + '-' + Date.now());
  }
});
var upload = multer({ storage : storage}).single('userFile');

// Configure app
var app = express(); 

// Store all html files in views 
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/views'));
// Parses recived json input 
app.use(bodyParser.json());
// Store all js in Scripts folder
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/scripts'));

// Technology not needed but good practice, especailly when serval people are working on it 
app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    res.sendFile('index.html');
}); 

// Listen for Seach collection request


app.post('/uploadFile',function(req,res){
    upload(req,res,function(err) {
        if(err) {
            console.log("Error uploading file"); 
        }else{
            var databaseName = "E-learn" , collection = "Uploads"; 
            var data = req.body;
            console.log("Got req:"+req);
        }
    });
});

// Implement a web server to listen to requests on port 4444 
app.listen(5555, function(){
    console.log('ready on port 5555'); 
});
```

Index.html

```
<!-- Page Content -->
<div class="container"  ng-app="fileUpload" ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading"><strong>Upload Files</strong> <small>Bootstrap files upload</small></div>
    <div class="panel-body">

      <!-- Standar Form -->
      <h4>Select files from your computer</h4>
      <form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="js-upload-form">
        <div class="form-inline">
          <div class="form-group">
            <input name="userFile" type="file" ngf-select="uploadFiles($files, $invalidFiles)" multiple accept="image/*" ngf-max-height="1000" ngf-max-size="1MB">
          </div>
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary" id="js-upload-submit">Upload files</button>
        </div>
      </form>
      <!-- Drop Zone -->
      <h4>Or drag and drop files below</h4>
      <div class="upload-drop-zone" id="drop-zone" ngf-drop ngf-select ng-model="files" class="drop-box" 
    ngf-drag-over-class="'dragover'" ngf-multiple="true" ngf-allow-dir="true"
    accept="image/*,application/pdf" ngf-pattern="'image/*,application/pdf'">
        Just drag and drop files here
      </div>
      <!-- Progress Bar
      <div class="progress">
        <div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="60" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width: 60%;">
          <span class="sr-only">60% Complete</span>
        </div>
      </div>
      -->
      <!-- Upload Finished -->
      <div class="js-upload-finished">
        <h3>Processed files</h3>
        <div class="list-group">
            <ul>
            <li ng-repeat="f in files" style="font:smaller"><span class="badge alert-success pull-right">{{f.name}} {{f.$errorParam}}</span>
              <span class="progress" ng-show="f.progress >= 0">
                <div style="width:{{f.progress}}%" ng-bind="f.progress + '%'"></div>
              </span>
            </li>
            <li ng-repeat="f in errFiles" style="font:smaller">
                {{f.name}} {{f.$error}} {{f.$errorParam}}
            </li> 
          </ul>
          {{errorMsg}}
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Result 
Error uploading file**

Comment: Have you looked at the browser dev tools in the network tab to see what the request looks like? Is the request sending the file data?

Comment: Yeah i looked at it. Im very sure its up there because i see -----------------------------2756737771435357697557051860
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="siu-logo.png"
Content-Type: image/png
PNG

Answer (score -1, accepted):

As Mitchell Simoens Said multer is a good option. Im guessing you need some help writing the code. So here is an example.

```
var multer = require('multer');
var storage = multer.diskStorage({
  destination: function (req, file, callback) {
    callback(null, './uploads');
  },
  filename: function (req, file, callback) {
    callback(null, file.fieldname + '-' + Date.now());
  }
});

var upload = multer({ storage : storage}).single('file');

app.post('/uploadFile',function (req,res){
  upload(req,res,function (err) {
    if (err) {
      console.log("Error uploading file"); 
    }

    var databaseName = "E-learn" , collection = "Uploads"; 
    var data = req.body;
    console.log("Got req:"+req);
  });
});
```

Comment: I get the follwing error. console.log("\n body: "+data);
                          ^
TypeError: Cannot convert object to primitive value

Comment: Sill getting empty info

Comment: Got req:[object Object]
file: [object Object]
filename:undefined
name:undefined
Stringify: {}

Comment: app.post('/uploadFile',upload.single('userFile'), function(req,res){

Comment: name input name=userFile

Comment: Error: Unexpected field
    at makeError (/home/Johnnyboy/Node/AngularUpload/node_modules/multer/lib/make-error.js:12:13)
    at wrappedFileFilter (/home/Johnnyboy/Node/AngularUpload/node_modules/multer/index.js:39:19)
    at Busboy.<anonymous> (/home/Johnnyboy/Node/AngularUpload/node_modules/multer/lib/make-middleware.js:112:7)
    at Busboy.emit (events.js:118:17)
    at Busboy.emit (/home/Johnnyboy/Node/AngularUpload/node_modules/busboy/lib/main.js:31:35)
    at PartStream.<anonymous> (/home/Johnnyboy/Node/AngularUpload/node_modules/busboy/lib/types/multipart.js:208:13)

Comment: The name should be var upload = multer({ storage : storage}).single('file');

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your express server isn't using any middleware to receive file uploads. body-parser isn't going to do it for you. I personally use [multer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/multer).

Comment: @John yea body-parser won't parse in files... that being said you shouldn't save the file itself to a database (don't know how'd you actually go about that), you should store the file itself on the server and then save a reference to the filename to the user :)

Comment: Ok i was looking at muler. And im confused on how i would use it for this case. I got to the point where its app.post('/searchcollection',multer({ dest: './'}).single('idk what this would be? '), function (req, res) {

Comment: The single method accepts a `fieldname` property that expects the file to be named this: https://www.npmjs.com/package/multer#single-fieldname

Comment: I dont think this is the problem. I tried adding multer as Andrew Kralovec has suggested  and im still getting empty info.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned, `body-parser` does not support file uploads, you need to use another module. Here's a simple implementation with [formidable](https://www.npmjs.com/package/formidable).

```
var async = require('async')
var formidable = require('formidable')

app.post('/uploadFile', function (req, res, next) {
  var form = new formidable.IncomingForm()

  form.uploadDir = '/my/upload/path'
  form.type = 'multipart'
  form.multiples = true

  form.parse(req, function (err, fields, files) {
    if (err) {
      return next(err)
    }

    // Each key in files is a file with the key being the input's name
    async.forEachOfSeries(files, function (file, inputName, cb) {
      // Do something with the files
    }, function (err) {
      next(err)
    })
  })
})
```

Comment: I dont think this is the problem. I tried adding multer and im still getting empty info.

Answer (score 0):

i hope this will work for you

```
var multer = require('multer');

app.post('/uploadFile',function(req,res){


     var your_filename = "";
        var storage = multer.diskStorage({ //multers disk storage settings
            destination: function (req, file, cb) {
               cb(null, __dirname + '/public/uploads/')
            },
            filename: function (req, file, cb) {
               var datetimestamp = Date.now(),
               file_name = file.originalname.split(".");

               your_filename = file_name[0]+'_'+datetimestamp+'.'+file_name[1];
               cb(null,  your_filename);
            }
        });
            var upload = multer({ //multer settings
                storage: storage
            }).single('file');

            upload(req,res,function(err){
                if(err){
                     res.json({error_code:1,err_desc:err});
                     return;
                }
               res.json({error_code:0,err_desc:null,filename:your_filename});
            })

})
```

message me if it still doesn't work